# How do I change/modify the displayed title of an NSPopUpButton

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I would like an `NSPopUpButton` to display a different title than the title of the menu item that is selected.

Suppose I have an `NSPopUpButton` that lets the user pick a list of currencies, how can I have the collapsed/closed button show only the currencies abbreviation instead of the menu title of the selected currency (which is the full name of the currency)?

I imagine I can override draw in a subclass (of `NSPopUpButtonCell`) and draw the entire button myself, but I would prefer a more lightweight approach for now that reuses the system's appearance.

The menu items have the necessary information about the abbreviations, so that's not part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `NSPopUpButtonCell`, override `drawTitle(_:withFrame:in:)` and call `super` with the title you want.

```
override func drawTitle(_ title: NSAttributedString, withFrame frame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) -> NSRect {
    var attributedTitle = title
    if let popUpButton = self.controlView as? NSPopUpButton {
        if let object = popUpButton.selectedItem?.representedObject as? Dictionary<String, String> {
            if let shortTitle = object["shortTitle"] {
                attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string:shortTitle, attributes:title.attributes(at:0, effectiveRange:nil))
            }
        }
    }
    return super.drawTitle(attributedTitle, withFrame:frame, in:controlView)
}
```

In the same way you can override `intrinsicContentSize` in a subclass of `NSPopUpButton`. Replace the menu, call `super` and put the original menu back.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    if let popUpButtonCell = self.cell {
        if let orgMenu = popUpButtonCell.menu {
            let menu = NSMenu(title: "")
            for item in orgMenu.items {
                if let object = item.representedObject as? Dictionary<String, String> {
                    if let shortTitle = object["shortTitle"] {
                        menu.addItem(withTitle: shortTitle, action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
                    }
                }
            }
            popUpButtonCell.menu = menu
            let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
            popUpButtonCell.menu = orgMenu
            return size
        }
    }
    return super.intrinsicContentSize
}
```

Comment: I specifically asked not to use custom drawing. I am not sure why you downvote my answer and post your answer that ignores my question…

Comment: And your solution may absolutely work, and I am thankful that you complete the page with your solution, but again…

Comment: Where do I use custom drawing? Ok, the explanation is a bit short, I'll edit that. Which question did I ignore?

Comment: The `drawTitle` method is doing the drawing (I admit, my wording could have been better as well) but then again I must admit, that maybe I am plain wrong here and you are correct. Mhmm… I apologize. I was blinded by the `draw` in the method name. Pfff stupid me

Comment: …and I'll leave my wrong comments above up in shame

Comment: BTW bindings don't use drawTitle, but I got it to work by overriding attributedTitle.

Comment: I tested with bindings (maybe other bindings) and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I found out how I can modify the title. I create a cell subclass where I override setting the title based on the selected item. In my case I check the represented object as discussed in the question.

```
final class MyPopUpButtonCell: NSPopUpButtonCell {
override var title: String! {
    get {
       guard let selectedCurrency = selectedItem?.representedObject as? ISO4217.Currency else {
           return selectedItem?.title ?? ""
       }
           return selectedCurrency.rawValue
       }
       set {}
    }
}
```

Then in my button subclass I set the cell (I use xibs)

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    guard let oldCell = cell as? NSPopUpButtonCell else { return }
    let newCell = MyPopUpButtonCell()
    newCell.menu = oldCell.menu
    newCell.bezelStyle = oldCell.bezelStyle
    newCell.controlSize = oldCell.controlSize
    newCell.autoenablesItems = oldCell.autoenablesItems
    newCell.font = oldCell.font
    cell = newCell
}
```

<s>A downside though is that I have to copy over all attributes of the cell I configured in Interface Builder.</s> I can of course just set the cell class in Interface Builder, which makes this superfluous.

**One thing I haven't figured out yet** is how I can have the button have the correct intrinsic content size now. It still tries to be as wide as the longest regular title.

**And the second thing I haven't figured out** is how to make this work with bindings. If the buttons content is provided via Cocoa Bindings then I can only bind the contentValues, and the cell's title property is never called.

Comment: You should use custom subclass of popupbuttoncell + "override func drawTitle(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)" and get your title from representedObject. It will draw only the selected item cell, not the menu.

Comment: I stated in my question that I don't want to draw the text myself.

Comment: Accepted. + why it's not possible to use custom class for cell in XIB (you copy it in awakefromnib)

Comment: In my xib I actually set the class and don't do it in awakeFromNib. Yeah I should have written that that is an equal possibility. I am not sure what you mean by 'recreating the whole menu' though. The presented solution is working fine except for the two remaining points. About which of those points are you talking about?

Comment: "A downside though is that I have to copy over all attributes of the cell I configured in Interface Builder." - it is confusing and part of answer to your question

Comment: Yes I fixed that, thank you. But that did work anyhow. It was just a bad way of doing it.

Comment: Cell size: try override "cellSizeForBounds:"

Comment: For bindings i don't have other solution than drawTitleWithFrame:

Comment: Is this an answer or more questions?

Comment: Well, I still don't know how to solve it using bindings (although Marek's answer would certainly work). And I am not sure how to really implement the intrinsic size yet.

Comment: Will a fixed size do?

Comment: Returning a fixed size (even if based on `controlSize`) is not the solution I am looking for. I know how to hack it together but I would be delighted to hear from someone who knows how to do it properly.

Comment: A fixed size isn't hacking, just a constraint. But if you replace the title, you can also replace `intrinsicContentSize` in the same way. I'll add an example to my answer.