# How do I keep NSMenuItem selected in a NSPopover with NSMenu?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have a NSPopUpButton with a built up NSMenu.

However, when an NSMenuItem is selected, it keeps going back to the first item.

[image: menu jumping back to default]

In this example, I'd expect "Maged" to be selected.

Any ideas?

Related question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387962/157656

Duplicate:

It's been suggested that this is a duplicate of the question 
[How do I change/modify the displayed title of an NSPopUpButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935340/how-do-i-change-modify-the-displayed-title-of-an-nspopupbutton)

"I would like an NSPopUpButton to display a different title than the title of the menu item that is selected."

However, my question was about getting the NSPopUpButton to show the selected item.

Comment: Which part is NSPopOver?

Comment: Sorry, I meant NSPopUpButton

Comment: The selected item is not an item of the menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change/modify the displayed title of an NSPopUpButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935340/how-do-i-change-modify-the-displayed-title-of-an-nspopupbutton)

Comment: It looks like Apple adds the selected item to the menu of the pop-up button. See the Region pop-up button in the Language & Region pref panel.

Comment: Does seem that way, but I'm glad I went with my answer then.  It's simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I changed how I did it.

I am using a NSButton to show the menu and NSTextField to display the results.

[image: current implementation]

If anyone is interested in the details, here they are.

Build the menu up and use .representedObject to store whatever you need to access at the other end.  I used a struct with the name and code the in it.

You need to assign the NSMenu to the NSButton.menu

Then have a click, something like this.

```
@IBAction func changeVoiceClicked(_ sender: NSButton)
{
    if let event = NSApplication.shared.currentEvent {
        NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(sender.menu!, with: event, for: sender)
    }
}
```

Your NSMenuItem should have an action on it, which using a selector points to a function.

Something like this:

```
@objc func voiceChanged(sender: NSMenuItem)
{
    // cope will nil
    var voice : VoiceDetail = VoiceDetail();

    if (sender.representedObject != nil) {
        voice = sender.representedObject as! VoiceDetail;
    }

    // Do what you need to on menu select.
    // update text field.
}
```